# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, interop

I am working on Windows Server 2008 R2 and have a component in my application that is supposed to manipulate word document, like Delete some table rows and Find and Replace a few words, based on input from user by Controls.

Everything is working fine on Localhost (Windows 7 / 64-bit System / 32-bit Office 2010)

But when I deployed the same code on Server, The Button click event is not responding. There is no error neither any exception. On the button click it should open the word file and then after add / delete it should save the file on a directory.

I have Same version of office installed both on Localhost and Server. I have Checked the Component Services and I cant see Microsoft Office Applications on localhost also on Server. Everything seems to be the same but still its not working on Server.

Comment: Don't do that.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/257757

Comment: Is your Microsoft Office even licensed to run on a server?

Comment: Does Word show up in the Task Manager processes list? Do you see any relevant error messages in the Events log? Are there any temp files or debris left from a failed process? You could try logging messages to see how far it gets before it dies.

Comment: I can see the WINWORD.EXE*32 on Server (In Task Manager Process list) when I open the MS Word Application.